# Find smallest substring containing a given set of letters in a larger string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, substring

Say you have the following string:

```
FJKAUNOJDCUTCRHBYDLXKEODVBWTYPTSHASQQFCPRMLDXIJMYPVOHBDUGSMBLMVUMMZYHULSUIZIMZTICQORLNTOVKVAMQTKHVRIFMNTSLYGHEHFAHWWATLYAPEXTHEPKJUGDVWUDDPRQLUZMSZOJPSIKAIHLTONYXAULECXXKWFQOIKELWOHRVRUCXIAASKHMWTMAJEWGEESLWRTQKVHRRCDYXNT
LDSUPXMQTQDFAQAPYBGXPOLOCLFQNGNKPKOBHZWHRXAWAWJKMTJSLDLNHMUGVVOPSAMRUJEYUOBPFNEHPZZCLPNZKWMTCXERPZRFKSXVEZTYCXFRHRGEITWHRRYPWSVAYBUHCERJXDCYAVICPTNBGIODLYLMEYLISEYNXNMCDPJJRCTLYNFMJZQNCLAGHUDVLYIGASGXSZYPZKLAWQUDVNTWGFFY
FFSMQWUNUPZRJMTHACFELGHDZEJWFDWVPYOZEVEJKQWHQAHOCIYWGVLPSHFESCGEUCJGYLGDWPIWIDWZZXRUFXERABQJOXZALQOCSAYBRHXQQGUDADYSORTYZQPWGMBLNAQOFODSNXSZFURUNPMZGHTAJUJROIGMRKIZHSFUSKIZJJTLGOEEPBMIXISDHOAIFNFEKKSLEXSJLSGLCYYFEQBKIZZTQQ
XBQZAPXAAIFQEIXELQEZGFEPCKFPGXULLAHXTSRXDEMKFKABUTAABSLNQBNMXNEPODPGAORYJXCHCGKECLJVRBPRLHORREEIZOBSHDSCETTTNFTSMQPQIJBLKNZDMXOTRBNMTKHHCZQQMSLOAXJQKRHDGZVGITHYGVDXRTVBJEAHYBYRYKJAVXPOKHFFMEPHAGFOOPFNKQAUGYLVPWUJUPCUGGIXGR
AMELUTEPYILBIUOCKKUUBJROQFTXMZRLXBAMHSDTEKRRIKZUFNLGTQAEUINMBPYTWXULQNIIRXHHGQDPENXAJNWXULFBNKBRINUMTRBFWBYVNKNKDFR
```

I'm trying to find the smallest substring containing the letters `ABCDA`.

I tried a regex approach.

```
console.log(str.match(/[A].*?[B].*?[C].*?[D].*?[A]/gm).sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length)[0]);
```

This works, but it only find strings where ABCDA appear (in that order). Meaning it won't find substring where the letters appear in a order like this: `BCDAA`

I'm trying to change my regex to account for this. How would I do that without using `|` and type out all the different cases?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Unsure, but you mean that "ABCZZAD" is ok if it is the shortest? You want the smallest part of the string that contains B, C, D and two A?

Comment: @miguel-svq yes - exactly

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896531/how-to-find-minimal-length-subsequence-that-contains-all-element-of-a-sequence

Comment: I don't see it as a duplicate, but for sure is close and is some kind of sub-case. S is the string, but don't want to find all the elements, just a subset of the S elements. At first look this could seem a simple problem, but it is not. (And don't see how to do it efficiently with regex)

Comment: I think there is no solution using regex.

Comment: Do you need a very efficient solution or just "something that works"? I mean: how long the real string will be, how often have to be "find" one of those set, how "realtime" iit needs to be, etc

Comment: Please look my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

Let's consider a special case: Assume the letters you are looking for are `A`, `A`, and `B`. At some point in your regexp there will certainly be a `B`. However, the parts to the left and to the right of the `B` are independent of each other, so you cannot refer from one to the other. How many `A`s are matched in the subexpression to the right of the `B` depends on the number of `A`s being already matched in the left part. This is not possible with regular expressions, so you will have to unfold all the different orders, which can be many!

Another popular example that illustrates the problem is to match opening brackets with closing brackets. It's not possible to write a regular expression asserting that in a given string a sequence of opening brackets is followed by a sequence of closing brackets of the same length. The reason for this is that to count the brackets you would need a stack machine in contrast to a finite state machine but regular expressions are limited to patterns that can be matched using FSMs.

Comment: Well... he can't "just with regex" . Regex have been his first approach but is not a condition in the question. ;)

Comment: I understand that he is trying to do it with regular expressions: "I'm trying to change my regex to account for this. How would I do that [...]"

Comment: What I have works when the `ABCDA` appears in order, I thought it would be possible to change so it would account for all the different orders it could appear in. But you are probably right :)

Comment: Unfortunately, the only solution I see is that you generate a regular expression containing all the different possible orders.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not as clear as using regex could be (well, for me regex are never really clear :D ) you can use brute force (not so brute)

Create an index of "valid" points of your string (those with the letters you want) and iterate with a double loop over it getting substrings containing at least 5 of those points, checking that they are valid solutions. Maybe not the most efficient way, but easy to implement, to understand, and probably to optimize.

```js
var haystack="UGDVWUDDPRQLUZMSZOJPSIKAIHLTONYXAULECXXKWFQOIKELWOHRVRUCXIAASKHMWTMAJEWGEESLWRTQKVHRRCDYXNTLDSUPXMQTQDFAQAPYBGXPOLOCLFQNGNKPKOBHZWHRXAWAWJKMTJSLDLNHMUGVVOPSAMRUJEYUOBPFNEHPZZCLPNZKWMTCXERPZRFKSXVEZTYCXFRHRGEITWHRRYPWSVAYBUHCERJXDCYAVICPTNBGIODLYLMEYLISEYNXNMCDPJJRCTLYNFMJZQNCLAGHUDVLYIGASGXSZYPZKLAWQUDVNTWGFFYFFSMQWUNUPZRJMTHACFELGHDZEJWFDWVPYOZEVEJKQWHQAHOCIYWGVLPSHFESCGEUCJGYLGDWPIWIDWZZXRUFXERABQJOXZALQOCSAYBRHXQQGUDADYSORTYZQPWGMBLNAQOFODSNXSZFURUNPMZGHTAJUJROIGMRKIZHSFUSKIZJJTLGOEEPBMIXISDHOAIFNFEKKSLEXSJLSGLCYYFEQBKIZZTQQXBQZAPXAAIFQEIXELQEZGFEPCKFPGXULLAHXTSRXDEMKFKABUTAABSLNQBNMXNEPODPGAORYJXCHCGKECLJVRBPRLHORREEIZOBSHDSCETTTNFTSMQPQIJBLKNZDMXOTRBNMTKHHCZQQMSLOAXJQKRHDGZVGITHYGVDXRTVBJEAHYBYRYKJAVXPOKHFFMEPHAGFOOPFNKQAUGYLVPWUJUPCUGGIXGR";
var needle="ABCD";
var size=haystack.length;
var candidate_substring="";
var minimal_length=size;
var solutions=new Array();
var points=Array();
for(var i=0;i<size;i++){
 if(needle.indexOf(haystack[i])>-1) points.push(i);
}
var limit_i= points.length-4;
var limit_k= points.length;
for (var i=0;i<limit_i;i++){
  for(var k=i;k<limit_k;k++){
 if(points[k]-points[i]+1<=minimal_length){
  candidate_substring=haystack.substr(points[i],points[k]-points[i]+1);
  if(is_valid(candidate_substring)){
    solutions.push(candidate_substring);
    if(candidate_substring.length < minimal_length) minimal_length=candidate_substring.length;
  }
 }
  }
}
document.write('<p>Solution length:'+minimal_length+'<p>');
for(var i=0;i<solutions.length;i++){
  if(solutions[i].length<=minimal_length) document.write('<p>Solution:'+solutions[i]+'<p>');
}

function is_valid(candidate_substring){
  //verify we've got all characters
  for(var j=0;j<candidate_substring.length;j++){
    if(candidate_substring.indexOf(needle.charAt(j))<0) return false;
  }
  //...and verify we have two "A"
  if(candidate_substring.indexOf("A")==candidate_substring.lastIndexOf("A")) return false;
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This algorithm doesn't use a regex, but found both solutions as well.

```
var haystack = 'FJKAUNOJDCUTCRHBYDLXKEODVBWTYPTSHASQQFCPRMLDXIJMYPVOHBDUGSMBLMVUMMZYHULSUIZIMZTICQORLNTOVKVAMQTKHVRIFMNTSLYGHEHFAHWWATLYAPEXTHEPKJUGDVWUDDPRQLUZMSZOJPSIKAIHLTONYXAULECXXKWFQOIKELWOHRVRUCXIAASKHMWTMAJEWGEESLWRTQKVHRRCDYXNTLDSUPXMQTQDFAQAPYBGXPOLOCLFQNGNKPKOBHZWHRXAWAWJKMTJSLDLNHMUGVVOPSAMRUJEYUOBPFNEHPZZCLPNZKWMTCXERPZRFKSXVEZTYCXFRHRGEITWHRRYPWSVAYBUHCERJXDCYAVICPTNBGIODLYLMEYLISEYNXNMCDPJJRCTLYNFMJZQNCLAGHUDVLYIGASGXSZYPZKLAWQUDVNTWGFFYFFSMQWUNUPZRJMTHACFELGHDZEJWFDWVPYOZEVEJKQWHQAHOCIYWGVLPSHFESCGEUCJGYLGDWPIWIDWZZXRUFXERABQJOXZALQOCSAYBRHXQQGUDADYSORTYZQPWGMBLNAQOFODSNXSZFURUNPMZGHTAJUJROIGMRKIZHSFUSKIZJJTLGOEEPBMIXISDHOAIFNFEKKSLEXSJLSGLCYYFEQBKIZZTQQXBQZAPXAAIFQEIXELQEZGFEPCKFPGXULLAHXTSRXDEMKFKABUTAABSLNQBNMXNEPODPGAORYJXCHCGKECLJVRBPRLHORREEIZOBSHDSCETTTNFTSMQPQIJBLKNZDMXOTRBNMTKHHCZQQMSLOAXJQKRHDGZVGITHYGVDXRTVBJEAHYBYRYKJAVXPOKHFFMEPHAGFOOPFNKQAUGYLVPWUJUPCUGGIXGRAMELUTEPYILBIUOCKKUUBJROQFTXMZRLXBAMHSDTEKRRIKZUFNLGTQAEUINMBPYTWXULQNIIRXHHGQDPENXAJNWXULFBNKBRINUMTRBFWBYVNKNKDFR';
var needle = 'ABCDA'; // the order of letters doesn't matter

var letters = {};
needle.split('').forEach(function(ch) {
  letters[ch] = letters[ch] || 0;
  letters[ch]++;
});

var shortestSubstringLength = haystack.length;
var shortestSubstrings = []; // storage for found substrings

var startingPos = 0;
var length;
var currentPos;
var notFound;
var letterKeys = Object.keys(letters); // unique leters
do {
  lettersLeft = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(letters)); // copy letters count object
  notFound = false;
  posStart = haystack.length;
  posEnd = 0;
  letterKeys.forEach(function(ch) {
    currentPos = startingPos;
    while (!notFound && lettersLeft[ch] > 0) {
      currentPos = haystack.indexOf(ch, currentPos);
      if (currentPos >= 0) {
        lettersLeft[ch]--;
        posStart = Math.min(currentPos, posStart);
        posEnd = Math.max(currentPos, posEnd);
        currentPos++;
      } else {
        notFound = true;
      }
    }
  });
  if (!notFound) {
    length = posEnd - posStart + 1;
    startingPos = posStart + 1; // starting position for next iteration
  }
  if (!notFound && length === shortestSubstringLength) {
    shortestSubstrings.push(haystack.substr(posStart, length));
  }
  if (!notFound && length < shortestSubstringLength) {
    shortestSubstrings = [haystack.substr(posStart, length)];
    shortestSubstringLength = length;
  }
} while (!notFound);

console.log(shortestSubstrings);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem in an interview as a coding assignment and came up with another solution, (it's not as optimal as the one above but maybe it's easier to understand).

```
function MinWindowSubstring(strArr) { 

  const N = strArr[0];
  const K = strArr[1];

  const letters = {};

  K.split('').forEach( (character) => {
    letters[character] = letters[character] ? letters[character] + 1 : 1;
  });

  let possibleSequencesList = [];
  
  const letterKeys = Object.keys(letters);

  for(let i=0; i< N.length; i++) {

    const char = N[i];

    if (new String(letterKeys).indexOf(char) !== -1) {
    
      // found a character in the string 

      // update all previus sequences
      possibleSequencesList.forEach((seq) => {
        if(!seq.sequenceComplete) {
          seq[char] = seq[char]-1;
          seq.lastIndex = i;

          // check if sequence is complete
          var sequenceComplete = true;
          letterKeys.forEach( (letter) => {
            if(seq[letter] > 0) {
              sequenceComplete = false;
            }
          });

          seq.sequenceComplete = sequenceComplete
        }
      })

      // create a new sequence starting from it 
      const newSeq = {
        startPoint: i,
        lastIndex: i,
        sequenceComplete: false,
        ...letters
      }

      newSeq[char] = newSeq[char]-1;

      possibleSequencesList.push(newSeq);
    }
  }

  // cleanup sequences 
  let sequencesList = possibleSequencesList.filter(sequence => sequence.sequenceComplete);
  
  let output = [];

  let minLength = N.length;
  // find the smalles one
  sequencesList.forEach( seq => {
      if( (seq.lastIndex - seq.startPoint) < minLength) {
        minLength = seq.lastIndex - seq.startPoint;
        output = N.substring(seq.startPoint, seq.lastIndex + 1);
      }
  })
   
  return output; 
}
```